# how to create vector object with 4 fields and 9 char length for each field

Tags: c++

Can anyone please script how to create a class for vector in c++, The requirement is there must be 6 objects, and each object must have 4 fields and each field must have 9 characters length. please help me am trying to learn. Am able to create vector and push data into it and display it, but could not do the requirement. thank you.

Comment: Your problem statement is too vague. What are 6 objects? You need a class of 4 strings of 9 characters? Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Break the entry into fields and save the fields in a C++ object. You can assume that no entry contains more than 4 fields and that no field contains more than 9 characters. Add the object to a vector. (If your object has a fixed length, you can use a vector of objects. Otherwise you need to use a vector of pointers to objects.)-on the whole I have 6 entries. This is what we need to do, (Am sorry this is my first post of question, I will improve how to ask clearly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean STL vector then you can use this :

```
class obj
{
    public:
    vector<vector<char> >v;
    obj()
    {
        v = vector<vector<char> >(4, vector<char>(9));
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<obj>array(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "6"?

Comment: You have "9 characters" and "4 fields" but missing "6 objects".

Comment: sorry :( i didn't notice that before :(

Comment: That creates a vector of objects which have no members.

Comment: my bad :( i'm an a***hole :'(

Comment: Erm no need to start insulting yourself?